# Getting meaningful results when executing arbitrary SQL statements (DML, DDL)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there a reliable way to get the type of an SQL statement (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, if possible also CREATE, TRUNCATE, DROP, ALTER...) without extensively parsing it? Do DBs return a reliable indicator for the type of the executed statement, ideally one that can be deducted from a `java.sql.PreparedStatement`?

To elaborate on the problem: A trivial way would be to check the first keyword, however this seems very error prone (e.g. statements starting with `WITH`, PL/SQL syntax, proprietary keywords and so on). The idea of reliably determining the type purely in Java without external resources seems daunting, especially when considering various DB vendors and versions (including future versions).

As far as I can tell, the most informative method to execute arbitrary statements is likely .executeUpdate(), as it returns the number of affected rows for writing statements; furthermore it won't return SQL errors for successfully executed DDLs (which from what I understand is the only indicator of success) and the `PreparedStatement` still has a retrievable `java.sql.ResultSet` for SELECT statements. But beside the fact that this would be in breach of various best practice approaches due to the misnomer/abuse of the method, this would still not give a clear indication of the type of the executed statement.

Comment: What for? Do you want to parse a query for some specific goal? What's the use case?

Comment: No quite the opposite actually, parsing is pretty much what I want to avoid (and might be outright impossible without DB specific implementations since different DBs interpret statements differently). What I want to do is pretty much what the title says, execute arbitrary statements and receive a meaningful result, which is different depending on the type of the statement (returning a result set for select statements, or a message "40 rows updated" for an update statement, "30 rows inserted for an insert statement, "table xyz created" for a create table statement and so on).

Comment: _"most informative method to execute arbitrary statements is likely .executeUpdate()"_ That is not correct. The most flexible way is using `execute()`. If it returns `true` the first result is a result set (use `getResultSet()` to get the result set), if it is false, it is an update count (use `getUpdateCount()`, if that returns -1, there are no more results), after processing that result, use `getMoreResults()` to process subsequent results, if any. Its return value has the same meaning as for `execute()` (true result set, false update count), etc.

Comment: This will allow you to process arbitrary results, but does not actually identify the type of statement at hand. There is no common way that database systems expose information like that (if they even expose such information, or if they don't use a different level of abstraction).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel Are you sure .execute() would be more flexible? Even if not, you are right that .getUpdateCount() can substitute the return value of .executeUpdate(), just like checking .getResultSet() for null could substitute the return value of .execute(). But even if they are equivalent in that regard, aesthetically .execute() would definitely be preferable. And perhaps you are right after all, in case there are DBs that refuse non-writing statements through .executeUpdate() (though I haven't encountered that yet).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The `execute()` method is for cases where you don't know what the result will be and how many results there will be (e.g. for example a SQL Server stored procedure can return multiple result sets and update counts in arbitrary order).

Comment: Just checking `getResultSet` for `null` is not a good substitute, because that would go against the protocol established for `execute()` and `getMoreResults()`, and calling `executeUpdate()` when the first result is a result set should produce an exception, and it is driver-specific if that exception happens *before* or *after* the statement is executed on the server, so trying that might work on one driver, but not on another (not to mention that the driver might clear results on exceptions, or rollback the transaction in auto-commit, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Determining the exact type of an SQL statement without parsing it extensively can be challenging, especially when you want to cover all possible SQL dialects and variations across different database systems. JDBC and the `PreparedStatement` interface do not provide a direct way to ascertain the statement type.

As you've mentioned, checking the first keyword might give you a rough idea but isn't foolproof due to the variety of SQL dialects and proprietary extensions. Additionally, using `executeUpdate()` for all statements isn't a good practice and won't reliably indicate the statement type.

A more reliable approach would involve parsing the SQL statement, but this can be complex and error-prone. There are third-party SQL parsers available that can help with this, but they may not cover every possible SQL variation.

Here are a few considerations:

1. **Database-Specific Features**: Some databases provide extensions or system tables/functions to determine the statement type. For example, PostgreSQL has `pg_stat_statements`, and Oracle has `V$SQL` for tracking SQL statements. However, these are database-specific solutions and not part of standard JDBC.
2. **Custom Logging**: Another approach is to log the SQL statements along with their types in your application for auditing purposes. This way, you can record the statement types at the time they are executed.
3. **Stored Procedures**: Encapsulating SQL statements within stored procedures can provide more control and auditing capabilities. You can create stored procedures for different types of statements and then call those procedures from your application.
4. **Query Builder**: Consider using a query builder or an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) framework like Hibernate. These tools often abstract away the need to write raw SQL statements and can provide a more reliable way to perform database operations.

In summary, while there isn't a foolproof, database-agnostic way to determine the exact type of an SQL statement using `PreparedStatement`, you can combine various approaches based on your specific requirements and constraints. Custom logging and database-specific features can be useful, but you may still need to rely on some level of SQL parsing or use higher-level abstractions provided by frameworks to make your code more robust and maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer, I appreciate it.
Regarding not using executeUpdate(), obviously you are right that it can't determine the type, I meant "most informative" as it returns the most information without knowing the type.
Are you sure parsing is more reliable? There are many cases how different DBs interpret statements differently (proprietary syntax, reserved keywords, priority of alias over keywords...).

Comment: As for your suggestions, the way I understand it 2.-4. are meant in a context of changing the objective. 1. is kind of what I was thinking of as a fallback. But unless I have a solution for every DB, .executeUpdate() might still be needed as the type would only be known after execution and could therefore not be used to determine the execution method.

Comment: And for the record, I fully understand your skepticism towards using.executeUpdate() for executing generic statements. The only reason I'm considering it is due to a perceived lack of alternatives. Comment spam over ;)